# automatic upload on dropbox from raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, dropbox

I am using  "Dropbox-Uploader" script from github on my raspberry pi to upload videos on my dropbox account.

https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader

its working great but now i want my raspberry pi to upload videos automatically on dropbox . for this i wrote python script

```
import os
path="/tmp/motion/"

def upload_files():
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        return
    os.stdir(path)
    for files in os.listdir("."):
        if files.endswith(".avi"):
            cmd = "/home/pi/dropbox_uploader.sh upload " + path + files
            os.system(cmd)
            os.system("sudo rm /tmp/motion/" + files)


if _name_ == "_main_":
    upload_files()
```

and set it as cronjob but its not working it is not uploading anything on my account. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Python is whitespace-sensitive, you have to indent your code correctly for it to run. That said, why are you writing a Python script that just starts a shellscript? Also, what is the meaning of "its not working"? Does it sit on the couch all day?

Comment: its not uploading videos on my dropbox account

Comment: Please read the guidelines at Stack Overflow. You are supposed to extract a minimal but complete example and a precise error description. There's a bunch of stuff going on, at what point exactly does the program stop behaving as expected, for example?

Answer (score 1):

I write a Script from many different Scripts and finally its working great.
Some things first to Install:
-you make a complete Update, Upgrade
I don't know right now all unneccary steps but I will write it down all here, and you can edit it by your own- but it still works and takes no harm on your Device.

STEP #1

copy + paste it to your terminal step by step:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-picamera
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip3 install unicornhat
pip install unicornhat
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install pip
sudo pip install dropbox
```

STEP #2

```
git clone https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader.git

curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader/master/dropbox_uploader.sh" -o dropbox_uploader.sh

chmod +x dropbox_uploader.sh

./dropbox_uploader.sh
```

-
You also need to get an Accesstoken from Dropbox.com
( https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps )

### You need to register an Account.

And I don't know if it is necessary but you need to have a file in MyApps, 
and give it a name " Raspi-upload "
+ my Settings inside:
Status: Development
Development User: Only you
Permission Type: Full Dropbox
Allow implicit grant: Allow

-
Then you have your KEY:

### I think you need this Key in Step #2 or You only need to Generate an ACCESS TOKEN

### On the next TAB [Branding] choose a Name.

- It takes a Photo every <10 seconds and uploaded it to your Dropbox app on your Phone.
- The Photo that is taken will be deleted after the Upload is finished, so you don't waste Space on your SD-card.

Here is the Script: #######TOP

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4

import dropbox
from dropbox.exceptions import ApiError, AuthError
import time
import datetime
import picamera
import sys, os
from time import sleep
import dropcamloop1

# Authorisation token
TOKEN = 'HERE IS YOUR ACCESS TOKEN'

# Format photo will be saved as e.g. jpeg
PHOTOFORMAT = 'jpeg'



# Create a camera object and capture image using generated filename
def camCapture(filename):
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
        print("Photo: %s"%filename + "." + PHOTOFORMAT)
        time.sleep(2)
        camera.capture(filename + '.' + PHOTOFORMAT, format=PHOTOFORMAT)



        print("Photo captured and saved ...")

        return filename + '.' + PHOTOFORMAT




# Generate timestamp string generating name for photos
def timestamp():
    tstring = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Filename generated ...")
    return tstring.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    #return tstring.strftime("image")


# Upload localfile to Dropbox
def uploadFile(localfile):

    # Check that access tocken added
    if (len(TOKEN) == 0):
        sys.exit("ERROR: Missing access token. "
                 "try re-generating an access token from the app console at dropbox.com.")

    # Create instance of a Dropbox class, which can make requests to API
    print("Creating a Dropbox object...")
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(TOKEN)

    # Check that the access token is valid
    try:
        dbx.users_get_current_account()
    except AuthError as err:
        sys.exit("ERROR: Invalid access token; try re-generating an "
                 "access token from the app console at dropbox.com.")

    # Specify upload path
    uploadPath = '/' + localfile

    # Read in file and upload
    with open(localfile, 'rb') as f:
        print("Uploading " + localfile + " to Dropbox as " + uploadPath + "...")

        try:
            dbx.files_upload(f.read(), uploadPath)
        except ApiError as err:
            # Check user has enough Dropbox space quota
            if (err.error.is_path() and
                    err.error.get_path().error.is_insufficient_space()):
                sys.exit("ERROR: Cannot upload; insufficient space.")
            elif err.user_message_text:
                print(err.user_message_text)
                sys.exit()
            else:
                print(err)
                sys.exit()



# Delete file
def deleteLocal(file):
    os.system("rm " + file)
    print("File: " + file + " deleted ...")



def main():

    # Generate name for file based on current time
    filename = timestamp()

    # Capture photo
    file = camCapture(filename)

    # Upload file
    uploadFile(file)

    # Delete local file
    deleteLocal(file)

    print("Done")
    #time.sleep(4)

    #x=0
    #while(x <4):
    #os.execv(sys.executable, ['/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/dropcamloop1.py'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

    time.sleep(4)


    x=3
    while(x <4):
        #os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] )
        execfile('dropcamloop.py')
    else:
        start ['dropcamloop1.py']
```

###END = dropcamloop1.py is the same file just the name is different.

IF You got any Question maybe I can help you there but aim not 100% sure.